# I am unable to use substring. How can I fix this?

Tags: c#

I am trying to see weather the string is in alphabetical order or no and this error pops up

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
>   Parameter name: length
>   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
>   at Rextester.Program.Main(String[] args)**

```js
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "bat\ncat\ndog\n";
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((str.Substring(i,i + 1).Equals("\n")))
        {
            c++;
        }

    }
    String[] strArray = new String[c + 1]; //declare with size
    int g = 0;
    String h = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((str.Substring(i,i + 1).Equals("\n")))
        {
            strArray[g] = h;
            h = "";
            g = g + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            h = h + str.Substring(i,i + 1);
        }
    }
    String p = "True";
    for (int i = 0; i < g; i++)
    {
        if (i < (g - 1))
        {
            String f = strArray[i];
            String g2 = strArray[i + 1];
            char d = f[0];
            char s = g2[0];
            int d1 = (int)d;
            int s1 = (int)s;
            if (d1 > s1)
            {
                p = "False";
            }

        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
}
```

Comment: IMHO split it, then check them. Only a few lines to do so and more effecient and less error prone.

Comment: You are missing a semi colon at the end of your first line.

Comment: That I fixed. The main issue is still the same

Comment: How does this question relates to Selenium?

Comment: Because I am getting the string from a web element

Comment: What do you mean webElement? That's not what you have up there in your post. If you are using selenium to pull string that you are checking the length on and if its null, you will get this error

Comment: It's not null. Don't worry about the selenium part

Comment: @tmk123 If we shouldn't worry about Selenium, then don't tag your question as that.

Comment: To see if two strings are in alphabetical order, you can use [String.Compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you are doing in your second loop and why is it so complex. We can do the same like this. Hope this helps.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    string str = "abcd";
    str = str.Replace('\n',' ');

    String p = "True";
    for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++) {  

        // if element at index 'i' is less  
        // than the element at index 'i-1'  
        // then the string is not sorted  
        if (str[i] < str[i - 1]) {
            p = "false";
        } 

    }  
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you change both the loops?

Comment: Yes I did change both

Comment: In C#, the substring method accept two parameters “startIndex” and length. First parameter will specify the starting position of the substring which has to be retrieve and second parameter will specify the length of the substring. The type of both the parameters is System.Int32. So, you need to have str.Substring(i,2) instead.

Comment: It compiled but still returns true even if the string is not in alphabetical order

Comment: I am just checking if the first letter of each word.
e.g 
bag  cat  dog. This is in alphabetical order.
cat bag dog This is not in alphabetical order

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the definition of substring

> The substring starts at a specified character position and has a
>   specified length

Considering your first use of substring, here

```
 for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
 {
      if (str.Substring(i, i + 1).Equals("\n"))
      {
                    c++;
      }
 }
```

What happens when we get to `i=6` here? Substring tries to give you a new string that starts at position `i = 6`, and is `length = 7` characters long. So it tries to give you 7 characters starting from str[6] to str[12]. Well, there is no str[12], so you get an exception.

Its clear that your intent is NOT to get a string that starts at position 6 and is 7 characters long. You want ONE character, so your loop should be this

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (str.Substring(i, 1).Equals("\n"))
    {
           c++;
    } 
}
```

But theres a much simpler way to get your words in alphabetical order using LINQ

```
 string str = "bat\ncat\ndog\n";

 //Removes the trailing \n so you don't have one entry that is only whitespace
 str = str.Trim(); 

 string[] strSplit = str.Split('\n').OrderBy(x => x[0]).ToArray();
```

Now all substrings are sorted alphabetically and you can do whatever you want with them

Comment: This helped! But what if the string does not have /n?

Comment: @tmk123 it depends. If its still using some kind of separator, like a pipe `|` or something, then you just change that character in the `.Split(char c)` call. Otherwise it is dependent on whatever structure exists in the data to keep entries separate.